# UITapGestureRecognizer Not Getting Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am adding the following UITapGestureRecognizer to my view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   _focusView = [[PBJFocusView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
   _focusTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_handleFocusTapGesterRecognizer:)];
   _focusTapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
   _focusTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   _focusTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
   [_previewView addGestureRecognizer:_focusTapGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)_handleFocusTapGesterRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

   NSLog(@"Focus");
}
```

Comment: u have the _previewView in subview of the view and has the some size

Comment: check userinteractionEnabled flag for your _previewView

Comment: What is the use of `_focusView`, is it parent of `_previewView`? If yes, make the frame bigger. Then set `_focusTapGestureRecognizer.enabled` to `YES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_focusTapGestureRecognizer should be enable. Try this

```
_focusTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
```

OR
Remove this line

```
_focusTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your code

```
_focusView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

May be helpfull...

Answer (score 0):

```
_focusTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

Remove this line

Answer (score 0):

To make this work check these three things as it is suggested by other guys i only writing them step by step

1. Check did you set the delegate of TapGesture in .h file.
2. Check on the UIView you are adding gesture its userInteractionEnabled is True.
3. Make that enable of UITapGesture Yes .//Why it is no ?
4. Fourth is , did you gave any size to the UIView , for checking that add some background color to it,see is it visible or not .

if these 4 doesnot help you out type your code what you used it .

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check that you're not trying to reuse the `UITapGestureRecognizer` object for different views.

It seems like you can because you add the gesture to the view, but in ultimately the view needs to be assigned to the `view` property on the gesture object so adding the gesture object to a second view will just overwrite the first.